# How to change token and authorization endpoint in ADFS 3.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, adfs3.0

Is there an option to change the oauth2 token and authorization endpoint in the ASFS 3.0?

Regards
Ajay MV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - they are pretty much proscribed by the specification.